# Is it possible to fully customize a sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

Alright, I received a job to fully customize a Sharepoint into a simple website, but all the information I found in google didn't helped and I don't know anybody who have worked with this, I have never seen those tags before, such as , so I need some infos about fully customization, is that possible? Where do I start from? I already installed the sharepoint 2010 and added the website but couldn't do anything.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: "Yes". You can do *anything* in SharePoint you can do with a standard ASP.NET service; of course, it's generally much better to use SharePoint how it was designed -- web-parts (even just "content"), page templates, list views, etc .. anyway, there is not enough information in this post to be useful. E.g. What sort of customization? What is the end-goal?

Comment: The customization I mean is changing everything to the ".psd" layout they gave to me, but the site looks like blank, and I can't even access without logging in, I am really lost in this job! haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look here , i think that you can find there answer http://idratherbewriting.com/2008/06/21/customizing-your-sharepoint-site-read-these-10-conceptsgotchas-first/